# Create a Custom Completion/Callback Handler to return Objects after a HTTP Request is Completed

Tags: java, android, event-handling, android-handler, androidhttpclient

I am an iOS Developer starting to learn Android. In Swift, creating a completion handler is very simple, but I still can't find a way to do it in Java.

I am sorry if this question is too noob for StackOverflow people.

**Problem**

I am creating a class to handle all my Http Request which is done using Retrofit.

I make this function is my `RequestHelper.java`

```
public static void checkEmailAvailability(String email) {
    MyWebServiceAPI serviceAPI = retrofit.create(MyWebServiceAPI.class);

    Call<APIResults> call = serviceAPI.checkEmailAvailability(getAuthenticationHeader(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email));

    call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResults>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<APIResults> response, Retrofit retrofit) { 
              //Parse Response Json
              //Get some value and place it inside an object
             //ANDI WOULD LIKE RETURN SOME BOOLEAN VALUE AND SOME OTHER STRING
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
              //I WOULD LIKE A BOOLEAN VALUE HERE            
        }
    });
}
```

I call it like this from my `MainActivity`

```
RequestHelper.checkEmailAvailability("user@user.com");
```

Now the function is still void but I would like for it to return something after the on the `onResponse` and `onFailure` method.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979480/replicating-swift-completion-handler-on-android-java Check this post

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `Callback` object as a parameter to the `checkEmailAvailability()`.

And implement the interface when you call the method from your `MainActivity`,and use the `response` parameter in the `onXXX()` method as the data returned to update UI.

Comment: I would like to have a different Callback (Custom). Because I am gonna parse the response and the return the value of it in a Callback.

Comment: @JayVDiyk You can do  something like: public void checkEmailAvailability (String email, final Callback<RestOauth> listener)   and  onResponse 
 if (listener != null) {
                            listener.success(retrofit, response);
                        }
onFailure 
if (listener != null) {
                            listener.failure(t);

Comment: @JeCuRo Thanks for replying. Let's say. I want to return a boolean value in the Callback. How would I go about to do it?